# I need help. I am trying to display the value of my buttons based on which option is clicked in another page in react js

Tags: reactjs

For instance, if the user clicks the 50 button, 50 should be displayed in the '/ProceedConfirmation' page like this [50]. I have tried if else conditions, etc. But its not working. Also, when I link my page to another page, it takes me to a different page before redirecting to the desired page. I am still new to reactjs, and I would really appreciate some help.

```
import React from 'react'
import './SelectAmout.css';
import {Button} from '../Button'
import button from './Withorwithoutcard'



function SelectAmount() {
      
    return (
        <div className='select-amount-container'>
            <div className = 'cancel-and-text'>
                <h3 className = 'amount-text'>Please select amount</h3>
                <img src='cancel button.png'
                    onClick = {() => window.location = '/SelectTransaction'}  
                    alt='Cancel selection. Go back to previous page'
                    className='cancel-pic'
                />
            </div>

            <p className = 'p1'> You can also enter your prefered amount</p>
            <p className = 'p2'> All amount are in GH</p>  
            {/*<div>{amount}</div>*/}
            {/*column 1*/}
            <div className = 'select-amount-btns-1'>
                <div className = 'amount-btns-list-1'>
                    {button &&<Button onClick = {() => window.location.href = '/ProceedConfirmation'}
                        className='amount-btns-list-1'
                        buttonStyle='secondary--btn'
                        buttonSize='stylished-medium-btn'   
                        >
                        50
                    </Button>}
                </div>
                <div className = 'amount-btns-list-2'>
                    {button && <Button onClick = {() => window.location.href = '/ProceedConfirmation'}
                        className='amount-btns-list-2'
                        buttonStyle='secondary--btn'
                        buttonSize='stylished-medium-btn'>
                        100
                    </Button>}
                </div>
            </div>
            {/*column 2*/}
            <div className = 'select-amount-btns-2'>
                <div className = 'amount-btns-list-1'>
                    {button && <Button onClick = {() => window.location.href = '/ProceedConfirmation'}
                        className='amount-btns-list-1'
                        buttonStyle='secondary--btn'
                        buttonSize='stylished-medium-btn'>
                        200
                    </Button>}
                </div>
                <div className = 'amount-btns-list-2'>
                    {button &&<Button onClick = {() => window.location.href = '/ProceedConfirmation'}
                        className='amount-btns-list-3'
                        buttonStyle='secondary--btn'
                        buttonSize='stylished-medium-btn'>
                        300
                    </Button>}
                </div>
            </div>
            {/*column 3*/}
            <div className = 'select-amount-btns-3'>
                <div className = 'amount-btns-list-1'>
                    {button &&<Button onClick = {() => window.location.href = '/ProceedConfirmation'}
                        className='amount-btns-list-1'
                        buttonStyle='secondary--btn'
                        buttonSize='stylished-medium-btn'>
                        400
                    </Button>}
                </div>
                <div className = 'amount-btns-list-2'>
                    {button && <Button onClick = {() => window.location.href = '/ProceedConfirmation'}
                        className='amount-btns-list-2'
                        buttonStyle='secondary--btn'
                        buttonSize='stylished-medium-btn'>
                        500
                    </Button>}
                </div>
            </div>

            {/*column 4*/}
            <div className = 'select-amount-btns-4'>
                {button &&<Button onClick = {() => window.location.href = '/'}
                    className='amount-btns-list-1'
                    buttonStyle='primary--btn'
                    buttonSize='large--btn'>
                    Enter Amount
                </Button>}
                </div> 
        </div>
    )
 
};




export default SelectAmount
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from '../Button';
import button from './Withorwithoutcard';
import './ProceedConfirmation.css';


function ProceedConfirmation() {
let amount;
  
        if (choice1) {
            amount = choice1; 
        }

        else if (choice2){
            amount = <div>100</div>
        }


    return (
        <div className = 'proceed-confirmation-container'>
<div className = 'cancel-and-text'>
                
                <img src='cancel button.png'
                    onClick = {() => window.location = '/SelectAmount'}  
                    alt='Cancel selection. Go back to previous page'
                    className='proceed-confirmation-cancel-pic'
                />
            </div>
            <p>You have requested to withdraw an amount of</p>
            <div>[{ amount }]</div>

            {/*<div>{amount}</div>*/}

            
            <div className = 'select-amount-btns-4'>
                {button && <Button onClick = {() => window.location.href = '/'}
                    className='amount-btns-list-1'
                    buttonStyle='primary--btn'
                    buttonSize='small--btn'>
                    Enter Amount
                </Button>}
        </div>

            <div className = 'proceed-tips'>
                <h4>Tips</h4>
                <ul className = 'proceed-tips-lists'>
                    <li>Please make sure your card is not damagedt</li>
                    <li>Please make sure you take out your card when you are done with your transaction
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
            </div>
    )
}

export default ProceedConfirmation
```

Comment: You can either include it in the URL and pass it around the application using react router, you can store this variable in a state inside a file above both pages (also called lifting the state up) - in a way that the variable will be usable in both pages. And yet a third option (more complex) is to use redux, which is basically a global state, and you can store variables globally.

Answer (score 1):

Use React Router and define routes with option to pass params like below.

```
<Route exact path="/ProceedConfirmation/:amount" component={ProceedConfirmation}/>
```

Write a button click handler in selectAmount Component as below. Repeat similar JSX for each button.

```
function SelectAmount(props)
{

 const handleAmountSelected = (amount) => {
 props.history.push('/ProceedConfirmation/?value={amount}');
 }

 return (
  ....
  ....

   <div className = 'amount-btns-list-2'>
                {button &&<Button onClick = {() => 
                    {handleAmountSelected(300)}}
                    className='amount-btns-list-3'
                    buttonStyle='secondary--btn'
                    buttonSize='stylished-medium-btn'>
                    300
                </Button>}
            </div>
      ...
     )
```

And in the ProceedConfirmation component you can fetch the value from url as

```
props.match.params.value
```

Incase if you don't want to use React-Router change the line in handler as below

```
handleAmountSelected(amount)
 {
 window.location.href = '/proceedConfirmation/?value={amount}'
 }
```

And in proceedConfirmation Component use QueryString to parse the value

```
import * as qs from 'query-string';
console.log(location.search);
//=> '?value=300'

const parsed = qs.parse(location.search);
console.log(parsed);
//=> {value: 300}
```